# Can esp8266 chip work safely in a circuit with 3.3v and 1 ampere current?

Tags: current, esp8266

I am using ams1117 to convert 5v/1A DC to 3.3v/1A using - https://iotbytes.wordpress.com/3-3v-power-supply-for-esp-8266/.

Can this 1 amp output (measured via ammeter) damage the esp8266 or i need to limit the input current (via resistor)?.

Comment: This is a duplicate, but I am too lazy to find one to refer to. Did you google?

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen yes, I did google it, and emphasis on correct voltage is there on many forums, but there was not much discussion on current requirements. At -   https://www.esp8266.com/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=12996 .  . 
The candy analogy was also helpful, but i wanted to be sure (i am beginner in electronics). 
"- candies store can afford delivering tons of candies, but the child just wish to get 12 candies, so it is ok !"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question has been asked many times before, in each case the person asking doesn't understand that what matters is the **voltage**. The load determines the current so there will be no 1 A flowing.

Not exactly a duplicate but it explains the **principle** behind voltage and current in relation to power supplies: [Choosing power supply, how to get the voltage and current ratings?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34745/choosing-power-supply-how-to-get-the-voltage-and-current-ratings/34746#34746)

To sum that up: you need to make sure that the ESP8266 gets the right **voltage** and then it will draw the current it needs. That current (needed by the load, the ESP8266) needs to be **lower** than what the supply can deliver. With the module your supply can deliver 1 A which is more than enough for an ESP8266.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. "will be no 1 A flowing" -  ammeter showed 1Amp , hence i was  concerned. 

The candy analogy was helpful - https://www.esp8266.com/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=12996.

Comment: How did you connect that ammeter to show 1A?

Comment: *ammeter showed 1Amp* If that's the case then you there's something wrong with your setup.